# How can i groupby ID and add columns to each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

```
     id  volume   location_ 10   location_ 100  location_ 1000  location_ 1002  location_ 1005  
0   14121   19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   14121   19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   14121   19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   14121   19  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   9320    200 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   9320    116 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   9320    200 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   9320    116 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have df like that. I want to groupby ID and i have to reach to something like that.
There is 4 id in 14121 and sum of their volumes is 76. How can i do that?

```
   id    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ... vol
0 14121  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...  76
1 9329   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ... 632
2 14934  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 ...   4
```

Comment: what are the columns 0,1,2,3,4,5,6.7.... ? I assume vol is sum of volume by group ID

Comment: `df.groupby('id')['volume'].sum()`?

Comment: `df.groupby('id').agg({'vol':'sum'})` should work I guess,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the location columns are. Here's how you would get the sum of ids.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[14121,14121,14121,14121,9320,9320,9320,9320,14934,14934,14934,14934],
                   'volume':[19,19,19,19,200,116,200,116,1,1,1,1]})
print (df)
print (df.groupby('id')['volume'].sum())
```

Input DataFrame:

```
       id  volume
0   14121      19
1   14121      19
2   14121      19
3   14121      19
4    9320     200
5    9320     116
6    9320     200
7    9320     116
8   14934       1
9   14934       1
10  14934       1
11  14934       1
```

Output DataFrame:

```
id
9320     632
14121     76
14934      4
```

Or you can also give:

```
print (df.groupby('id').agg(vol_sum = ('volume','sum')).reset_index())
```

Output will be:

```
      id  vol_sum
0   9320      632
1  14121       76
2  14934        4
```